# Red5 steaming inconsistent connections audio

Tags: jwplayer, red5

I am trying to test what the issue is with Red5, Jwplayer and streaming audio files.
Basically jwplayer only sometimes makes a proper connection and plays the mp3. Also with certain browsers other than FF not at all. Then at some points FF will stop making connections.

Now when trying to make connection the jwplayer will either do nothing when hitting play button, load the song and play, or sometimes show the track position bar like it just loaded but then do nothing. If it does start playing then skipping forward throughout the track is fine.

If in a european location closer to the server then this does not appear to be an issue and the mp3 will load fine in FF Chrome IE etc.

The server a dedicated server provides other content from Europe to North America quite fast so I don't think its a server issue but rather a jwplayer or red5 setting.
Jwplayer has 'bufferlength: '1',' and the red5.properties has:

```
    # RTMP
    rtmp.host=0.0.0.0
    rtmp.port=1935
    rtmp.io_threads=16
    rtmp.send_buffer_size=65536
    rtmp.receive_buffer_size=65536
    rtmp.ping_interval=1000
    rtmp.max_inactivity=60000
    rtmp.max_handshake_time=50000
    rtmp.tcp_nodelay=true
    rtmp.default_server_bandwidth=10000000
    rtmp.default_client_bandwidth=10000000
    rtmp.client_bandwidth_limit_type=2
    rtmp.bandwidth_detection=true
    rtmp.encoder_base_tolerance=5000
    rtmp.encoder_drop_live_future=false
    rtmp.traffic_class=24
    # requested maximum length of the queue of incoming connections
    rtmp.backlog=10
    # the interval (seconds) between each throughput calculation
    rtmp.thoughput_calc_interval=1
    # enable io event throttler
    rtmp.throttle_enable=false
    # io event size threshold
    rtmp.throttle_threshold_size=65536
    # max connections to allow when throttling is in effect
    rtmp.throttle_max_permits=128
    # keep-alive for io threads when using an executor
    rtmp.executor_keepalive_time=3000
```

Are there any settings with red5 here or with jwplayer that I should look to be changing the values to help resolve this issue?

Or is there something on the server I could change. I had read about mod_deflate causing problems but I since found out it is disabled anyways.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: I cannot at this time sorry as it is a locked dev site.

Comment: Sorry, would need a link in order to debug properly.